# Opinions on NTFS for Mac solution?

Tags: macos, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-3g, paragon

I am currently using the free NTFS-3G to access my NTFS drive from the Mac.  It seems pretty stable (except once in the very beginning, it locked up the Mac and corrupted my NTFS drive, which I then fixed with chkdsk from a PC).

However, speed is NOT one of its virtues.  In fact, it's painfully slow

I've been looking at buying [Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X 8.0](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/). Their product comparison [PDF](http://www.paragon-software.com/export/sites/paragonsoftware.com/docs/NTFS4Mac_ProductPerformance_05.pdf) claims nearly double the speed (vs NTFS-3G) in almost every category (read, write, etc...).

In addition, there is now an [unsupported](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=785376) native solution with the snow leopard.

Can folks here share their experiences.  Is the native solution stable enough to be used for daily work?  Should I just go with Paragon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using it for a while now and it's far better than NTFS-3G, I never got a problem and it's very stable.

The price is a bit high but it is worth it on my own opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I used NTFS-3G for a while too but decided to buy the "pro" version (Tuxera NTFS for mac) from the same guys because of issues with unmounting and mounting external NTFS drives.

Tuxera feels completely stable (I have had no issues whatsoever with external drives since I got it) and also faster. I don't have any benchmarks but I used to have moments of "What's taking so long - oh right this drive is NTFS" with the free NTFS-3G, but not anymore.

It costs 25€ which I feel is a decent price for what it gives me.