# Native OS X RW NTFS support

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ntfs, read-write, paragon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any opinions on Paragon’s NTFS for Mac solution?](https://superuser.com/questions/95238/any-opinions-on-paragons-ntfs-for-mac-solution)

I understand that OS X Snow Leopard unofficially has [Read/Write capability for NTFS](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=785376).  Any experiences with it? Is is stable enough for daily heavy use? Or should I spring for Paragon NTFS?

Comment: please update your old question if you didn't get enough information the last time around.  closing as a duplicate.

Comment: How is this a dup?  I am asking about the native RW NTFS capability.  The previous question was about Paragon's NTFS for Mac solution.

Comment: it's tagged [paragon] and asks which to use.  the difference is this one is about native NTFS vs paragon, while the other is NTFS-3G vs paragon.  why *not* put them all together?

Comment: Ok, done.  Deleting this question.